# Writing ArcPy code to modify multiple attribute records?

Tags: arcpy

How and where can I write a script or code, what can I run and it computes all of the values according to a few column values?

The base column values can change, so with this method I can avoid running field calculators in every single column when the original few columns value have changed.

With this method, I would be able to run a code only once, and it would compute every column (or field) with running only one code.

Comment: try arcpy.da.updatecursor

Comment: And where, how to use that? Where can I write an arcpy code?

Comment: Okay, how to create an arctool with arcpy script or with just arcpy to do this what I want? I can't find a good tutorial anywhere...

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide clarifications to it.

Comment: I would write clarification everytime when I have any idea about how to describe...and thanks the -3 vote a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact there are many ways to do a field calculation on several fields based on a single base filed. I have given simple sample for DOUBLE operation on the base field(i.e Serial) e.g. field named **"Double"** is double of field named **"Serial"** and **"Treble"** is double of field named **"Double"**. ***It can be customised as one needs.***

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

CWS_GRID_Point = r"C:/Users/Winrock/Documents/ArcGIS/CWS_GRID_Point.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

Field_Name_1 = "Double" # provide a default value if unspecified
Field_Name_2 = "Treble"

# Local variables:

Expression_Type = "PYTHON"
Code_Block = "def getDouble(field):\\n    return field*2"

# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(CWS_GRID_Point, Field_Name_1,"getDouble(!Serial!)", Expression_Type, Code_Block)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(CWS_GRID_Point, Field_Name_2,"getDouble(!Double!)", Expression_Type, Code_Block)
```

Just for testing place this code in the arcpy console after modifying variables.

[image: CalcField]

Comment: Should I always use \\n when I want to break line in the Code_block? The first "\" is necessary too? Or what should I do if I would have long functions?

Comment: Of course not, i just added extra "\" just for esthetic. You can add any number (1-4) but ONE is must.

Comment: What is the problem syntactically with this code? http://pastebin.com/Hw2Xq3YG I would like to pick someone up in Skype, because I spend a lot of hours and still don't have too much success in Python scripting. But I don't want to spend more hours about discovering things, because I don't really have much time for that.

Comment: And can't I attach a better IDE for ArcGIS? Because that console window is the worst option for coding I have ever seen...

Comment: You may try pyscripter(free) or wing ide(it costs).